# Creating a nested routed for a collection as opposed to member

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

When I create a nested route, it creates it for a member.

```
  resources "/my_items", ItemController do
    get "/route123", Item.SubItemController, :route123 
  end
```

The route will be "/my_items/:id/route123". How can I create the same nested route but for a collection?

"/my_items/route123"

Comment: There are no collection routes inside `resources`, but you can always do `get "/my_items/route123", Item.SubItemController, :route123` before `resources`.

Comment: @Dogbert, thx....

Comment: @Dogbert Consider posting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are no collection routes inside resources, but you can always do

```
get "/my_items/route123", Item.SubItemController, :route123
```

before resources.

Copied from @dogbert's comment.